Folder and File Naming in React Native
I'm curious about the conventions or best practices for naming folders and files in a React Native project. Are there any specific rules or guidelines regarding the usage of parentheses in folder names like (auth)/(tabs), or naming files with underscores such as _layout.jsx? If there are no explicit rules, what are the reasons behind choosing such naming conventions for folders and files in React Native projects? I'd appreciate insights and recommendations from experienced React Native developers.


See Expo documentation: https://docs.expo.dev/router/layouts/.
